# I need a low volatility asset that gives an interest/dividen

Tags: dividends, interest, low-volatility

I have some cash that needs to sit on an account for some time (less then a year, where I will withdraw an amount every month).
I need them in a fixed price/low volatility asset that gives an interest every month or so. Any suggestions?

I looked into dividend ETFs, but they are highly correlated with SP500 and I don't want to be impacted by the stock markets movements.

Can you guys think of something?

Cheers
TY

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't give financial advice and I don't believe that Money.SE would give such advice either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at money market ETFs?

Something like Pimco's MINT http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MINT

Answer (score 0):

In addition to money market ETFs already mentioned, have you considered short term bond ETFs like VGSH and VCSH? [This is what I use]. They offer a bit more yield, though admittedly at a slightly higher duration risk.

https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=3142&FundIntExt=INT

https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=3145&FundIntExt=INT